# What's wrong with this particular question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Normally I avoid discussion about my questions / answers. The new code of conduct (COC) says welcome and be friendly to a new user. I [talk about this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53551719/unnumber-the-parargarapgh-using-the-jquery/53551903#53551903). I edited and answered this question. The question got downvoted and an answer also. The question got one close vote too.

1. The OP shows attempt on the question.
2. The OP doesn't dump his/her home work.

What's wrong with this question? I am not questioning about the answer downvote. I want to know about the question. What's wrong with this question? Does it deserve to be closed?

Comment: Nothing much wrong with the question.  It could use a "this is much harder to do correctly than you might think" answer.  Not everybody likes a hard question.

Comment: Note the *original* question, before edits, is a mess. I can't tell when exactly you got this downvotes, it could be before your edit.

Comment: @jpp: the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53551719/timeline) can tell you. Also, noteworthy, the Triage results: "Looks Okay * 3". 

Comment: Whoever voted that the original question looks ok needs a review ban...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, first of all, this got nothing to do with the new Code of Conduct. Downvoting and even closing questions is **not** unfriendly, it's just trying to keep the overall high quality of Stack Overflow (by signalling low quality content via downvotes) and keeping the site clean of off topic questions. It becomes unfriendly when snarky comments are posted, and that's what the CoC try to reduce.

Now for [the question itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53551719/how-to-reset-paragraph-numbering-done-with-jquery). Its first revision was terribly formatted and worded, meaning OP spent zero efforts on it. Some people take it as "they didn't bother so they don't deserve to be helped", which is valid point. Second revision was better, but still in bad shape. As for the question contents, which should be what matters most, they appear to be legit, I believe that if the current revision would have been the first, the question would get an upvote or two to begin with.

Bottom line, what's done is done. Score of -1 is really not that bad, the question is not closed, no snarky comments. In the future just try to edit such questions into shape (both formatting and wording, sometimes they need total rewording to make sense) as soon as possible, and they'll have better chance.

Answer (score 5):

If I *wanted* to nitpick, someone glancing at the question may presume that the ID for the jQuery operation and the ID for the actual div doing the work is different.

If I take ~30 seconds to really look at what is going on, I could see that the click action which invokes the titling is driven by a completely different thing, but it *does* actually invoke the appropriate HTML.

Someone nitpicking may believe that the code is "incomplete" in this state.

I don't see it that way but I could see how it could be seen that way.